# Why does "npm script" appear in my explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Why does "npm script" appear in my explorer? I haven't used node.js or installed related plug-ins, but it does exist in my explorer.

Does it come with the editor? Or is it because I installed other plug-ins? How do I completely remove it on the mac system, because I don’t want to see it for a thing I don’t use.

[image]

Comment: Just right-click on it and uncheck it to hide it.  Yes, it is built-in.  I don't believe you can remove it from vscode.

Comment: @Mark Thank you, buddy. At first I thought it only appeared because I installed the plugin. Yes, it exists in every virtual machine of mine. Although this may be convenient for some people, not every vs coder uses node.js. I think it is not a good idea to have it built-in and displayed by default.

Comment: Since there was another question about this, I went ahead and answered it there, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63583395/836330