# how do I hide a pane in the Explorer sidebar in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The latest version of VSCode (1.48.1) has added a new pane in the Explorer sidebar. It now shows:

- Open editors
- [current project's files]
- Outline
- Timeline
- NPM scripts

I have no use of the NPM scripts, and even minimized, it's taking up one line of space which would be more useful to show more open files, for instance.

Is there a way to get rid of it completely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click on the "NPM Scripts" header bar (or any of the Explorer views in your list) and deselect/uncheck it to hide it.  I don't think there is any way to get rid of it completely, just to hide it.

[image: hide NPM Scripts view from Explorer panel]